# Combine two qualified names

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is there an easy way to combine two NameSyntax objects into one QualifiedName object?

The following code is not working, because the SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName method is expecting a SimpleNameSyntax object as second argument.

```
NameSyntax part1 = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Part1"), SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Part2"));
NameSyntax part2 = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Part3"), SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Part4"));

QualifiedNameSyntax combined = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(part1, part2);
```

This could be a solution, but I have the feeling that there must be a better way, without the ToString and parse:

```
NameSyntax combined = SyntaxFactory.ParseName(part1.ToString() + "." + part2.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any API methods for this. But you can try the following

```
public QualifiedNameSyntax Combine(NameSyntax left, NameSyntax right)
{
  var qn = right as QualifiedNameSyntax;
  if (qn != null)
  {
    return SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(Combine(left, qn.Left), qn.Right);
  }

  var sn = right as SimpleNameSyntax;
  if (sn != null)
  {
    return SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(left, sn);
  }

  throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```